# WebDriverException from Selenium firefox_binary.py only when ran from mod_wsgi

Tags: python, selenium, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am running Python 2.7, Virtualenv, Django 1.3, mod_wsgi, Apache application on Ubuntu 11.04.
Everything including psycopg2 etc are working great with wsgi and app are up and running.
The only issue is with Selenium. I am getting this error **ONLY when I execute this from wsgi** on creating firefox driver as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
```

> WebDriverException Exception Value:    Message: "Can't load the profile.
>   Profile Dir : /tmp/tmp8h7MW8"

my Selenium version is 2.5
Apache launched as root and child process are launched as user called app.

Execute the code above from same virtualenv without wsgi works just fine.

So this makes me think that it is permission issue at some level... so I tried this:

```
ls -l /tmp/tmp8h7MW8
>> drwxr-xr-x 3 app app 4096 2011-10-07 13:09 extensions
>> -rw-r--r-- 1 app app 2188 2011-10-07 13:09 user.js
```

I would appreciated it if you could point me to right direction as to what I am might be misconfiguring wsgi

Answer (score 1):

Apache processes run as special user. If that temp directory is truly owned by 'app' then Apache user likely wouldn't be able to write to it.

What user does Apache run as? Are you using daemon mode and overridden what user it should run as?

Comment: here is the permissions:
    `$ ls -l
    drwxr-xr-x  4 app app  4096 2011-10-04 11:18 tmp

    $ ps aux | grep apache2
    root      5007  0.0  0.1  10280  4004 ?        Ss   14:14   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    app   5104  0.0  0.0  10280  2284 ?        S    14:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    app   5105  0.1  0.7 254368 24112 ?        Sl   14:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    app   5106  0.1  0.7 254372 24124 ?        Sl   14:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`

I am not specifying the mode. So I believe it is running in daemon mode.. Is this correct?

Comment: What are User/Group directives set to in Apache config? Are you using WSGIDaemonProcess/WSGIProcessGroup directive in Apache/mod_wsgi config? If you are, have you set user/group options to WSGIDaemonProcess at all? The Apache process appear to be running as 'app' but please confirm by looking at config.

Comment: Apache Config I set to app:
`User app
 Group adm` 
this is the 'app' user's groups: `$groups app >> app : app adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape dip video plugdev fuse
--
I did not setup any user/group option set in mod_wsgi config. here is my .wsgi file:

>WSGIScriptAlias / /home/app/myapp/apache/django.wsgi
><Directory /home/app/myapp/apache>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
></Directory>

Comment: Since it would appear not to be permissions, unless you are using SELinux and it is imposing something strange, then check that you are always using absolute paths in your app to refer to stuff and not relative as current working directory of Apache could be anything, usually / and not where your app is.

Comment: SELinux is not installed. I checked wsgi config file and vhost config and as far as I can see I am not using relative path. All starts from /home/app/... I posted as issue on selenium and see if they could give me places I could look further. [Link to Selenium Ticket](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2635&thanks=2635&ts=1318101801)

Answer (score 1):

So I traced firefx_binary.py and figure it out the actual error was "Connection refused" when socket_.connect(("127.0.0.1", self.profile.port)) is called.
The port value changes every time (ie: 45807, 44719, 60565)

The error occurs depends on Group setting on apache config (apache run user and group) as Graham suspected. I was playing with 2 users.

```
$ groups app
app : app
$ groups nreeves
nreeves : nreeves adm dialout fax cdrom floppy tape dip video plugdev fuse
```

I tried 3 patters and only 1 works which still confuses me and hope someone could tell me why...

```
# this does't work...
User=nreeves
Group=adm

# this does't work either
User=app
Group=app

# this works
User=nreeves
Group=nreeves
```